# Which is a status bar,an activity or service?

Tags: android, statusbar

I just wonder Which is a status bar,an activity or service?
Can I check whether the status bar is pulled down or not?
Thanks

Editted:
THis is status bar that I meant: [image: statusbar]

Comment: this bar http://developer.android.com/images/status_bar.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can think status bar is a service [StatusBarManager](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/StatusBarManager.java) with a ui, when the status bar pulled down, your activity will invoke `onStop`, when the status bar pulled up, your activity will invoke `onResume`

Comment: Thank you, I think it a service too. But what I need is to check whether it pulled down or not to make my service open up an activity.

Answer (score -1):

Staus bar notification can be triggered from both Activity/Service, you will usually create status bar notifications from a service. This way, the notification can be created from the background, while the user is using another application or while the device is asleep.I hope this link help you understand more. [Status bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to add a notification ; but know the status of the notficatin bar itself.